# Into what eschatological category do the teachings of the Catholic Church fit?

Tags: catholicism, eschatology

I don’t think I’ve heard much from Catholics on the topic. It seems that they would be removed from the dispensational-premillennialism hysteria, but haven’t heard many speak on it one way or another.

Comment: Related: [On Amillenialism and the Catholic Church](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/64294/21576)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The eschatological summary which speaks of the "four last things" (death, judgment, heaven, and hell) is popular rather than scientific. For systematic treatment it is best to distinguish between (A) individual and (B) universal and cosmic eschatology, including under
>
> (A):
>   death;
>   the particular judgment;
>   heaven, or eternal happiness;
>   purgatory, or the intermediate state;
>   hell, or eternal punishment;
>   and under
>
> (B):
>   the approach of the end of the world;
>   the resurrection of the body;
>   the general judgment; and
>   the final consummation of all things.
>
> The superiority of Catholic eschatology consists in the fact that, without professing to answer every question that idle curiosity may suggest, it gives a clear, consistent, satisfying statement of all that need at present be known, or can profitably be understood, regarding the eternal issues of life and death for each of us personally, and the final consummation of the cosmos of which we are a part.

From:
http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/05528b.htm